# Creating a unique ID for an object in YapDatabase

Tags: swift, database, relational-database, yapdatabase

Suppose I have a collection of Users in a YapDatabase. How do I assign each user a unique identifier upon creation?

```
struct User: Codable{
     public var name: String
     private var id: ???
}
```

I've seen UUID in the Apple developer documentation. Having done some reasearch, it seems more for use in distributed systems, athough I suppose it could work. Are there other alternatives? Is there a "standard" method for giving objects a unique id in a relational database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible variants:

1) String (unique everywhere & forever)

```
struct User: Codable{
     public var name: String
     private var id: String // = UUID().uuidString
}
```

2) Int (unique inside your users context, enough in majority of cases)

```
struct User: Codable{
     public var name: String
     private var id: Int = 0 // = lastUser.id + 1, where 0 is a new non stored
}
```